# python how to create a string that is 4 characters long from a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to input a number from 0 to 1000 and have python return a string that is always 4 characters long.
for example: input 10 python should return 0010

Comment: OR: `str(10).zfill(4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zero padding format with fixed width:

```
"{:04d}".format(number)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: It makes a string from a number in the fixed width format (4 characters) and uses zeros rather than spaces for padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, Hope this helps

```
num = 10
if num < 1000:
    print "%04d" % (num,)
```